# Short link stability

Tags: discussion, support

When I use a short links such as the [link](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/q/45/136) to this question are there any guarantees how long the link will remain viable assuming this question is not deleted?

I ask this question because I just noticed that the short link in this [comment](https://np.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/4vfqmh/stackmonero_twitter_feed/d5zg7pq) which I presume originally pointed [here](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18/are-stackexchange-twitter-bots-run-by-stackexchange-or-the-community) is now pointed [here](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25/i-just-joined-without-being-invited-is-that-bad)

When questions are closed, are existing questions renumbered, thereby harming accuracy of short links referencing question numbers?

I am working on the [StackMonero](https://twitter.com/stackmonero) Twitter bot and desire stable links. Should I be using this [short](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/q/45/136) format or this [long](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45/short-link-stability) one? My preference is for the short link format but not at the expense of stability.

[StackBitcoin](https://twitter.com/stackbitcoin) appears to be using the shorter formating with an `atw=1` modifier while [StackEthereum](https://twitter.com/stackethereum) appears to use the longer formatting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Links are valid forever, unless a question is deleted. The link you posted from reddit, points to: `/q/25/255` and it actually makes sense because the poster asks if this is related to twitter (i.e., is `/q/25` related to `/q/18`).

So, `/q/25/255` basicly means **question** with id **25** referred by user with id **255**. The important part is the `q` and the `25`. The part that comes after the slash can be basicly anything,`/q/25/i-like-popcorn` is also a valid link and will always open the question 25.

> When questions are closed, are existing questions renumbered, thereby harming accuracy of short links referencing question numbers?

No, IDs wont change never.

> I am working on the StackMonero Twitter bot and desire stable links. Should I be using this short format or this long one? My preference is for the short link format but not at the expense of stability.

Use `http://meta.monero.stackexchange.com/q/45` - everything after that is optional, like: `http://meta.monero.stackexchange.com/q/45/coming-from-twitter` ;-)

By the way, I'm running one of the ethereum twitter bots, if you have any additional questions.

Comment: Thank you very much! Which one of the two Ethereum bots do you run? @ethoverfloow or @stackethereum? I am very interested in your algorithm to determine what is Tweeted

Comment: I'm running [@ethoverflow](https://twitter.com/ethoverflow), it's using a modified [feedr rss bot](https://github.com/housed/feedr).

Comment: thank you! I will look at that bot this week.